# Return a new string list from the key and the value of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a dictionary with two lists:

```
d = {}
for i, (building,egid) in enumerate(zip(df["DESTINATIO"],df["EGID"])):
    d.setdefault(building, []).append(egid)`
```

Here are the results.

[image: Dictionary]

Now I have another string list:

[image: List with string]

and each time the value of the list is equal to the value from the dictionary, the string of the list will be take the key from the dictionary.

I've tried this.

```
type_building_neighbours=[]
for neighbours,(key, value) in zip(df['Desired_neigbours'],d.items()):
    if neighbours==value:
        replacement=string.replace(neighbours,key)
        type_building_neighbours.append(replacement)`
```

Unfortunatly I got an empty result.

What I expect is the same string list but instead of having the string with numbers I will have this result:

`0 NAN
1 NAN
2 NAN
3 Caserne
4 Caserne
5 NAN
6 Compostage 
etc..`

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)... [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: using `zip` twice _hints_ to me that your flow is incorrect. That's not an absolute at all, but I think we need example input and expected output

Comment: @roganjosh, I gave an output. The input is the dictionary and the string's list